Как воспроизвести аудио, не записывая его в файл, python, pydub
Я получаю аудио данный в байтах и мне нужно воспроизвести его, не записывая в файл.
from pydub import AudioSegment  
from pydub.playback import play
from elevenlabs import VoiceSettings
from elevenlabs.client import ElevenLabs

client = ElevenLabs(api_key = api_key,)

def generate_response(voice_id: str, text: str):
    response = client.text_to_speech.convert(
        voice_id = voice_id,
        optimize_streaming_latency = "0",
        output_format = "mp3_22050_32",
        text = text,
        voice_settings = VoiceSettings(
            stability = 0.6,
            similarity_boost = 0.2,
            style = 0.3,
        ),
        language_code = "en",
        model_id = "eleven_turbo_v2_5"
    )

    output = io.BytesIO()

    for chunk in response:
        output.write(chunk)

    return output

play((generate_response("pFZP5JQG7iQjIQuC4Bku", "Hi, my name is Lily!")))


output — это переменная, содержащая аудио в байтах. Как воспроизвести его с помощью pydub и методов AudioSegments?

А по документации play что должен на вход принимать?
